# What is “No. 79378”?

Tags: discussion, design

The new site design<sup>1</sup> has as part of the [background image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/skepticsmeta/img/bg-header.png?v=446553b999e8) this:

[image: No. 79378]

It appears just to the left of Questions, Tags, Users, etc., at least for me. It appears to be a hand-written case-number or something on some kind of old official form – which seems quite fitting, but now I’m wondering if that number itself has any significance. A Google search didn’t return anything.

<sup>1. And quite possibly the old one, since I’m a lurker and didn’t spend enough time here to say for sure it *didn’t* have it... but I’m pretty sure it’s new.</sup>

Comment: Perhaps it's the number of design iterations for this site.

Comment: There are other numbers and letters and even a seal in that image. Why only focus on this one?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Mostly because it’s front and center, at least for me. But sure, V452 / M37 and 119715 deserve some attention,

Comment: Conspiracy theorists know where that image is from...  Right?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Any hints? I spent 30 minutes searching without any further leads.

Comment: I wished it's an easter egg that refers to post with ID 79378 on Skeptics.SE, but apparently I was wrong since the site doesn't have that many posts. :(

Answer (score 14):

### Partial answer:

This looks more like a Puzzling SE post, but I suspect that the No. 79378 image probably comes from a list of well-known forgeries.

The "V452 M37" string can be found from a [fake "Kenyan" birth certificate of Barack Obama](https://archive.org/download/BarackObama-BornInKenya-TheDocumentary/Lucassmith-BarackObamaIiKenyanBirthCertificate.jpg), in the bottom right hand corner.

The stamp in the same image (with the title "Coast Province General Hospital, Mombasa Seal Kenya") can also be found in the upper right corner of the Skeptics title image.

[image]

The stamp and the numbers are identical to the birther document. A higher resolution version of the birther document can be found on the [links on this page](http://www.obamaconspiracy.org/2009/09/latest-filings-in-barnett-v-obama/) referring to the [Barnett v Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama_presidential_eligibility_litigation#Barnett_v._Obama) case.

I have also attached a contrast-enhanced version of the title image.
[image]

Comment: Bravo! Great answer (Still we don't know what does the number 79378 mean). Didn't expect this to be about the birth cerficiate rumours of Obama :D